# What is the proper way to test if a job has manually failed?

Tags: laravel, testing, queue, jobs

In a Laravel app I have a job which I want to fail manually if some condition is not met. The code works fine in the sense that the job does what it should do, but I want to write a feature test just to be on the safe side.

Here's an oversimplified version of the job:

```php
class ExampleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        // Some initial logic

        if (! $foo->exampleMethod()) {
            event(new ExampleEvent($foo));
            $this->fail();
        }

        // Some final logic which I expect not to be reached if the job should fail

        dd('You should not get here');
    }
}
```

This is the test I have at the moment:

```php
/** @test */
public function foo()
{
    Event::fake();

    Bus::fake();

    ExampleJob::dispatch();

    Queue::after(function (ExampleJob $event) {
        $this->assertTrue($event->job->hasFailed());
    });

    Event::assertDispatched(ExampleEvent::class);
}
```

What is the proper way to test if the job failed manually?

I tried several approaches but none worked.

It seems that inside the test the code execution continues after the `$this->fail()` statement and reaches the `dd()` statement.

Comment: `hasFailed()` should still return true. Are you sure that `$this->fail()` is actually being called? Note there is also an `ExampleJob::failed()` method you can implement that receives an exception you can do with as you please.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's called because when the job runs for real (not in a test) I can see it as failed in Horizon with the `ManuallyFailedException`.

Comment: I mean, are you sure it's called in the test?

Comment: I'm doing `ExampleJob::dispatch();` so I'm expecting it to be called, but I don't know for sure really.